# Switch android device from user to engineer version and vise-versa? Root device to Unrooted device?

Tags: android, shell, operating-system, adb

I am looking for an option to switch device software from Engineer version to user version i.e device have root access but need to disable root access of an Android device.

Is there a way such that we can toggle between root enable/disable option.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, no implementation of this in stock.
There are some stuff and hacks that can do that, like ***Magisk***. Check this out.